# create a function that validates date using jquery ajax and php checkdate() function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am making a function in Jquery that validates the date given, by accessing  checkdate.php using ajax.  checkdate.php uses checkdate() and returns "success" if the date is valid. Here is my jquery function.

```js
function checkdate(sample)
  {
  $.get('checkdate.php?dateSample='+ sample, function(data){
    if(data == 'success')
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  });
  }
```

checkdate.php works with no error and I'm sure of that but my problem is when I use this code ->

```js
alert(checkdate('2013-09-22'));
```

or

```js
alert(checkdate('123123123iuo12'));
```

it always alerts `"Undefined"`

I need Boolean result from checkdate function. Please help me.

Comment: Or, it's all because ajax calls are usually "asynchronous". It does not wait for result to come back so it's undefined.

Comment: If you use the jquery-validate plugin, it has a `remote` method that makes it easy to use AJAX for validation.

Comment: davidkonrad gave me a link that answers my question but i still cant apply that to my function. I also avoid putting so many plug ins hahha.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
function checkDate(date)
{
    $.ajax({
        method: 'post', // or GET
        url: 'checkdate.php',
        data: {dateSample: date},
    }).done(function(response){
        alert(response);
        // do stuff ...
    });
}

checkDate('test');
```

Comment: Ok i'll try your solution. Currently I solved my problem by setting async to false, but they said it is not advisable, so i'll try this haha